# How do you calculate the combinations of balls moving across columns?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

At the start, in Column 1 there are a set of balls (say, 10 balls).

Then any or none of those balls in Column 1 move across to Column 2.

Then any or none of those balls in Column 1 and Column 2 move across to Column 3.

Then any or none of those balls in Column 1, Column 2, and Column 3 move across to Column 4.

Then any or none of those balls in Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, and Column 4 move across to Column 5.

And so on.

A new column is added each time and any balls from columns before could move across to it.

How do you calculate the total possible number of combinations?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: The answer depends on whether or not the balls are indistinguishable or not or if the columns are indistinguishable.  Ultimately the answer after $n$ steps will likely depend on partition numbers.